# What is meant by parallelism in this case?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, akka

In this blog post about parallel collections in Scala http://beust.com/weblog/2011/08/15/scalas-parallel-collections/

This is mentioned on a comment by Daniel Spiewak:

> Other people have already commented about the mkString example, so I’m
>   going to leave it alone. It does reflect a much larger point about
>   collection semantics in general. Basically, this is it: in the absence
>   of side-effects (in *user* code), parallel collections have the
>   *exact* same semantics as the sequential collections. Put another way:
>       forAll { (xs: Vector[A], f: A => B) =>
>       (xs.par map f) == (xs map f)
>       }

Does this mean that if there are no side effects parallelism is not achieved? If this is true can this point be expanded to explain why this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will always be run in parallel, but the result may differ when side-effects are there.

Let's say `A = Int` and `B = Int` with following code:

```
var tmp = false

def f(i: Int) = if(!tmp) {tmp = true; 0} else i + 1
```

So here we have a function f with a side-effect. I assume that `tmp` is `false` before running the code.

Running `Vector(1,2,3).map(f)` will always result in `Vector(0,3,4)`

But `Vector(1,2,3).par.map(f)` can have different results. It can be `Vector(0,3,4)` but since its parallel, the second element maybe is mapped first etc. So something like this might happen `Vector(2,0,4)`.

You can be sure that the result will be the same, when in this case `f` would not have side-effects.

Comment: @Kiygo So when .map is applied to a collection in parallel the ordering of the elements in the new mapped collection is dependant on the order of when each map function finishes processing on each element ?

Comment: I think that the order of the elements always stays the same. Just the order in which the function f is applied to the elements may vary, since it is parallel and there is some racing involved i guess.

Answer (score 4):

> Does this mean that if there are no side effects parallelism is not
>   achieved?

No, that's not what it means. When Daniel Spiewak says that

> Basically, this is it: in the absence of side-effects (in user code),
>   parallel collections have the exact same semantics as the sequential
>   collections.

It means that if your function has no side-effects then using it to map over a simple collection or a parallel collection will yield the same outcome. Which is why:

> Put another way: forAll { (xs: Vector[A], f: A => B) => (xs.par map f)
>   == (xs map f) }

if `f` is side-effect free.

So, it's actually the opposite: if there are side effects parallelism is not a good idea since the outcome will be inconsistent.